# How to make $q and $http work together?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I am trying to get this code to work

```
getDataObject = {
    transformData: function (wmsLayer) {
    var promise = this.getDataFromServer(wmsLayer);
    promise.then(
        function(XMLInput){
            layers = $(XMLInput).find('LayerDescription').each(function() {
                var item = $(this);
                var layerName = item.attr('name');
                layerNames.push(layerName);
            });       
            },
        function(data){
                this.error(data)
                });
},

getDataFromServer: function(wmsLayer) {
var deferred = $q.defer();
var layerGroup = wmsLayer.params.LAYERS[0];
    $http.get({
        url : '//localhost/geoserver/BL_WFS/wms',
        params : {
            service : 'WMS',
            version : '1.1.1',
            request : 'DescribeLayer',
            layers :  layerGroup,
        },
        responseType : 'xml'
    })
    .success(function(data){
        deferred.resolve(data);
    })
    .error(function(error){
        deferred.reject(error);
    });
return deferred.promise;        
}
```

But I am running in two problems:

1. Although I set the url in the $http the function keeps calling the url which the page comes from.
2. I would like to execute `transformData` function only when the response has got back with the data and I am not sure I designed the promise/defer structure correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you're using angulars shorthand $http.get. This one has function signature of $http.get(url, config) so it should be

```
$http.get('//localhost/geoserver/BL_WFS/wms', {
    params : {
        service : 'WMS',
        version : '1.1.1',
        request : 'DescribeLayer',
        layers :  layerGroup,
    },
    responseType : 'xml'
})
```

Secondly, $http already returns a Promise object you can use which gets automatically resolved or rejected so you can return that directly in this case.

**Source**: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Edit: Keeping the angular documentation at hand and checking it for this is always a good idea.

Comment: I changed the code but I am still running in problem n.2. When I get to the `then()` method of the promise the code of success does not get executed, the code flow just skips that method, goes on and gets done after all the function has finished running. There is more going on after the array has been populated. I tried to copy all the code inside the then method but it is still the same. When it gets to then() it does not go inside.

Comment: Yes thanks for your answer I had a look at the code and I needed to tweak some other things to get the code to execute when I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Although @SargoDarya's answer is correct, I thought I'd clarify how you can change your code.

Change this:

```
getDataFromServer: function(wmsLayer) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var layerGroup = wmsLayer.params.LAYERS[0];
    $http.get({
        url : '//localhost/geoserver/BL_WFS/wms',
        params : {
            service : 'WMS',
            version : '1.1.1',
            request : 'DescribeLayer',
            layers :  layerGroup,
        },
        responseType : 'xml'
    })
    .success(function(data){
        deferred.resolve(data);
    })
    .error(function(error){
        deferred.reject(error);
    });
    return deferred.promise;        
}
```

To this:

```
getDataFromServer: function(wmsLayer) {
    var layerGroup = wmsLayer.params.LAYERS[0];
    return $http.get('//localhost/geoserver/BL_WFS/wms', {
        params : {
            service : 'WMS',
            version : '1.1.1',
            request : 'DescribeLayer',
            layers :  layerGroup,
        },
        responseType : 'xml'
    });       
}
```

Since `$http.get` returns a `promise` already.